# requirejs text plugin downloads all templates which are not required

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm using RequireJS along with text plugin to load the Handlebar templates dynamically in Backbone Layout Manager. But on page load all the templates get downloaded instead of the specified one.
In the case shown below when I just want to render footer all the files (`header`, `modal`) gets fetched instead of only `footer.tpl`.

**templateLoader.js**

```
define(function (require) {
    var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

    var getTemplateFile = function (templateName) {
        var tmpl = null;
        switch (templateName) {

        case 'header':
            tmpl = require('text!../html/templates/header.tpl');
            break;
        case 'footer':
            tmpl = require('text!../html/templates/footer.tpl');
            break;
        case 'modal':
            tmpl = require('text!../html/templates/modal.tpl');
            break;
        }
        return tmpl;
    };


    var _compiled = function (tpl, context) {
        var compiled = Handlebars.compile(tpl);
        return context ? compiled(context) : compiled;
    };

    return {
        getTemplate: function (templateName, model) {
            return _compiled(getTemplateFile(templateName), model);
        }
    }
});
```

**MyView.js** - LayoutManager

```
App.Views.StoreFooter = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    beforeRender: function () {
        this.$el.html(Templates.getTemplate('footer'));
    }
});
```

When I check the resources downloaded in Chrome I see `modal.tpl`, `header.tpl` which should not be there according to above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side-effect of the *syntax sugar*, described in the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) :

---

```
define(function (require) {
    var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
        dependency2 = require('dependency2');

    return function () {};
});
```

> The AMD loader will parse out the require('') calls by using Function.prototype.toString(), then internally convert the above define call into this:

```
define(['require', 'dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (require) {
    var dependency1 = require('dependency1'),
        dependency2 = require('dependency2');

    return function () {};
});
```

---

Since it parses the function body as a string, it has no way of seeing that the `require` statements are inside a `switch` which is guaranteed to only match one `case`.

**edit:**

I thought this could be fixed by refactoring your code a bit:

```
var getTemplateFile = function (templateName) {
    var path = null;

    switch (templateName) {
    case 'header':
        path = 'text!../html/templates/header.tpl';
        break;
    case 'footer':
        path = 'text!../html/templates/footer.tpl';
        break;
    case 'modal':
        path = 'text!../html/templates/modal.tpl';
        break;
    }

    return require(path);
};
```

Unfortunately, this causes:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "text!blah.txt_unnormalized2" has not been loaded yet for context: _

...which makes sense when you realise this is just *syntactic sugar*, not a way to make RequireJS work in synchronous mode.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. How can i go about on this? I was following an example given here.. https://github.com/efeminella/requirejs-template-module-example/blob/master/src/app/templates/Templates.js